# Using Page_Load and Page_PreRender in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

I see some people are using Page_Load and Page_PreRender in same aspx page. Can I exactly know why do we need to  invoke both the methods in same asp.net page?

Please see the code below,

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            dprPager.ButtonClickPager += new EventHandler(dprPager_ButtonClickPager);

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
              InitPager();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }

    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        erMsg.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblError.Text);
    }
```

Comment: You don't  *need* to use both, is there a specific example that you're having trouble understanding? `Page_Load` gets called first, and later on `Page_PreRender` will be called.

Comment: Please check I have added the code.

Comment: I'm trying to determine whether a postback was caused by by 'add' button server control or by a page refresh so that I can stop a record being inserted into my asp:GridView upon page refresh.

But I can't find the Page PreRender event after looking here:


http://aspalliance.com/687_Preventing_Duplicate_Record_Insertion_on_Page_Refresh.4

I'm unfortunately having to post here as S.O has stopped my asking new questions :(

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It depends on your requirements.

Page Load : Perform actions common to all requests, such as setting up a database query. At this point, server controls in the tree are created and initialized, the state is restored, and form controls reflect client-side data. See Handling Inherited Events.

Prerender :Perform any updates before the output is rendered. Any changes made to the state of the control in the prerender phase can be saved, while changes made in the rendering phase are lost. See Handling Inherited Events.

Reference: **Control Execution Lifecycle MSDN**

Try to read about

[ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

[Control Execution Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719775%28vs.71%29.aspx)

Regards

Comment: Why cannot I move all logic to PreRender?

Answer (score 37):

The major difference between `Page_Load` and `Page_PreRender` is that in the Page_Load method not all of your page controls are completely initialized (loaded), because individual controls `Load()` methods has not been called yet. This means that tree is not ready for rendering yet. In `Page_PreRender` you guaranteed that all page controls are loaded and ready for rendering. Technically `Page_PreRender` is your last chance to tweak the page before it turns into HTML stream.

Answer (score 2):

Page_Load happens after ViewState and PostData is sent into all of your server side controls by ASP.NET controls being created on the page. Page_Init is the event fired prior to ViewState and PostData being reinstated. Page_Load is where you typically do any page wide initilization. Page_PreRender is the last event you have a chance to handle prior to the page's state being rendered into HTML. Page_Load
 is the more typical event to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Well a big requirement to implement PreRender as opposed to Load is the need to work with the controls on the page. On Page_Load, the controls are not rendered, and therefore cannot be referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Processing the ASP.NET web-form takes place in *stages*. At each state various `events` are raised. If you are interested to plug your code into the `processing flow` (on server side) then you have to handle appropriate page event.

Answer (score 0):

The main point of the differences as pointed out @BizApps is that Load event happens right after the ViewState is populated while PreRender event happens later, right before Rendering phase, and after all individual children controls' action event handlers are already executing.
Therefore, any modifications done by the controls' actions event handler should be updated in the control hierarchy during PreRender as it happens after.